# Stand-alone Error Page with translated text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, translation, country-codes

I'm working on a website that will deployed internationally. Very big site, but for the sake of simplicity, all we're concerned about is my Error.aspx with c# code behind.  I'd like to make this custom error page as dynamic as possible.  There's at least a handful of languages we need to read this page in right now, and more to come.  This page needs to work independently and without a database to reference.

I'd like to have some text, and have the appropriate translation appear based on the language appropriate for that domain... e.g. ".com" = English, ".ca/fr" = French, ".mx" = Spanish... you get the idea.

What's the best way to do this?

I've looked into API's, but the decent ones have a cost threshold, and while it might look really helpful, this is just pretty standard error message text, that's unlikely to change, so that seems like overkill to have a dynamic translator.  It might help with scalability, but it's extra money indefinitely, when it will only save vs hard-coding on the handful of occasions where we add another language/country/domain.

The other idea I had was to simply hardcode it in the c#.  parse out Request.URL and get the domain, and make a ever-growing switch statement which would assign the appropriate text.  (As an aside, I'm also trying to find a better way to do this, but is the country code something that would be an available piece of information from either the request object or server?) This way would be independent, precise, and the only drawback on a concrete level would be the cost of adding new languages, or changing every string (probably not that many, at least at first) if the content of the error message needed to be adjusted.  But this feels like bad practice.

I've been researching this for a day now, but I haven't found any alternatives to these 2 options.  What are the best practices for handling small amounts of text for translation, without the use of a CMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy built-in way to handle localization in ASP.NET Web Forms.  It uses the Language Preference settings in the client's browser to select the language.  Posting the steps of setting it up would be redundant since there's lots of information on this subject available online.  [Here is a good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38907/ASP-NET-Localization-Quick-Reference).

EDIT:
It might be a good idea to read up on HTML resource files.  That is the HTML standard for handling different languages (referred to as localization).  And it is what ASP.NET uses in the background when creating a local resource for a server control.

Comment: Great resource, exactly what I was looking for, and I'd heard the term localization, should've connected those dots, Thanks!

Comment: So just a minor hiccup in the process - I just got told that the Culture needs to be set by domain... I can retrieve this, and I can compare it to what the page is currently loading as, and if it differs, I can set the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture to the new value, but on redirecting back to the same page, the culture setting is what the browser had said it was on the way in initially... is there a way to reload it to a different resx specically?